# C++ passing by reference and casting confusion

Tags: c++, casting, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Say I have `Object o` which contains a vector defined as:

```
std::vector<V *> V;
```

and I have a getter:

```
inline std::vector<V *>& getV() { return V; };
```

if I am passing a parameter in by reference:

```
void A::function(Object& o)
```

and trying to access items in `std::vector V`;

How should I do this?

```
void A::function(Object& _o)
{
        for (int f=0; f < _o.getV().size(); f++)
        {
            V* _v = _o.getV().at(f);

            std::string s = _v->getName().c_str();

            std::cout << "V: " << _v->getName().at(f) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "V: " << s << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

What mistake am I making if I am crashing when trying to acces `_v->getName()` above.

If I look at the crash I do see that _v has positions filled:

```
V   std::__1::vector<V *, std::__1::allocator<V *> >    size=8
[0] V * 0xbfffd658  0xbfffd658
[1] V * 0xbfffd658  0xbfffd658
[2] V * 0xbfffd658  0xbfffd658
[3] V * 0xbfffd658  0xbfffd658
[4] V * 0xbfffd658  0xbfffd658
[5] V * 0xbfffd658  0xbfffd658
[6] V * 0xbfffd658  0xbfffd658
[7] V * 0xbfffd658  0xbfffd658
```

UPDATE: So it seem that the previous dev did something like this at one point

in a .h 
    `Object* o1;`

in .a cpp

```
void B::function(Object& _o)
{
    o1 = &_o;
     .... does stuff with o1 .....
}
```

in another .cpp passes in the original `object o` to do stuff with it:

```
void A::function(Object& _o)
{
        for (int f=0; f < _o.getV().size(); f++)
        {
            V* _v = _o.getV().at(f);

            std::string s = _v->getName().c_str();

            std::cout << "V: " << _v->getName().at(f) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "V: " << s << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to say, but do you have an unhandled exception? `_v->getName().at(f)` may not be a valid index. Also did you notice that the address of the pointers are all the same in your vector (they all point at the same thing)?

Comment: @JesseGood - I did notice that and I am trying to figure out why. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Having a pointer of vectors is difficult to get right. It is much easier working with a vector of objects, i.e. `std::vector<V>`. Also, please check whether `f < _v->getName().size()` before calling `_v->getName().at(f)`, it may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Let me look. I posted an update as well

Comment: Nice catch @JesseGood, There was zero reason to use pointers here. I removed making it just a vector of objects and everything is as expected. Do you see why they might have done that? I guess impossible to tell.

Comment: Pointers may be used to save on space and speed when the objects are very large, but generally that is a premature optimization and without seeing more code, its hard to tell.

Comment: can you answer the question so I can accept? i.e, Vector of Objects vs Pointers comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain what exactly is going on in your posted code without more information, but since your problem seems to be solved, [as per requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394006/c-passing-by-reference-and-casting-confusion#comment27015403_18394006), using a vector of pointers is difficult to get right and should be only used in certain situations, such as when you realize there could be a huge performance gain (after testing) or the type you are dealing with is non-copyable, etc. Also, when dealing with pointers, you have to be extra careful about object lifetime, proper copying (deep copy vs. shallow copy), proper comparison (comparison between pointers vs actual objects) and is tricky to get right. Therefore, always store the objects directly in the container when you can, and change to a vector of pointers when you have to.